# crystal report error "A string is required"

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports-xi

I wrote a formula to calculate the discount percentage in crystal report.I have retrieved the discount amount from the back end and need to get the discount percentage through this.
Disc% = Discount Value/(Quantity*Price) * 100
quantity and price also I got from the back end.my formula is,

```
IF(({row.DISCOUNT})<>0) then(({@discVal})/( ({@quantity}) * ({@price}) * 100)) else 0
```

I'm new to this.Therefore please help.

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz5EC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your {row.DISCOUNT} is a string rather than a number.
Either make sure it's a number or use a Crystal formula to convert it to a number.
For example:

```
cDbl({row.DISCOUNT})
```